# Python: how to generate a list of words from a string and save it in a text file according to their index?

Tags: python

```
with open('filename.txt', "r") as word_list:
    words = word_list.read().split('')


with open("file.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(words))
```

But the output is not in order (I want one word per line) as I want them to be. My apology: I am a very beginner in python. Thanks in advance if anyone can figure out how I can sort words using python according to the index from the list.

Comment: You are splitting over `''`, that's one problem; I assume you either want to split over line endings `.split('\n')` or perhaps over any whitespace `.split()`. What do you mean 'according to index'?

Comment: Thanks a lot! By according to index I mean the output would be like:
0. Word1
1. Word2
2. Word3
etc.

Comment: If you just mean their position in the input file, then what do you mean by "sort words using python according to index" - the order wouldn't have to change, since you just read them in order?

Comment: I actually want the numbering of words according to their index in the list..

Comment: Can you add an example of input and expected output?

Comment: Input: Random string read from a text file
Output: Words in that string. So that one word in one line numbered (e.g. 0: word, 1:word, 2:word etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
with open('filename.txt', "r") as word_list:
    words = word_list.read().split(' ')

with open("file.txt", "w") as output:
    for index, word in enumerate(words):
        output.write(f'{index}. {word}\n')
```

The code uses the built-in [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to loop through the list of words with an index (0-based). It also uses string interpolation (so called [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)) to build the correct output string.